# Pattern matching between two files in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, script, grab

I have two .rtf file....
The first one have this content:

> Apple, Orange, Banana, Noodle, Chip

The Second File is something like this:

```
     Apple I love eat Apple.
     Banana I hate Banana.
     Zoo I want to go Zoo.
     Noodle Noodle can be a very very very very very very very very very very very long, but still is one line.
     Chip Don't eat so many chip. 
     Orange Orange is great, not Apple plx. Noodle
     Water Drinking water is boring.
```

The first file is a "key" of second file.

In the second file, the first word is the key of each line.

Each key and sentence in second file, ONLY have one line. The Second File have many lines with keys, but not all the keys are present in `file1`, but `file1`'s key MUST be in the second file.

How can I get the result like this: (Need to sort by the key from `file1`)

```
  Apple, Apple I love eat Apple. 
  Orange, Orange is great, not Apple plx.
  Banana, I hate Banana. 
  Noodle, can be a very very very very very very very very very very very long, but still is one sentence. 
  Chip, Don't eat so many chip.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make some assumptions (which you seem to agree with in your question).

1. Key file is a CSV of keys (comma separated list of key words)
2. Data file has keys as the first words starting at the first column

   - this constraint can be managed with some more things in the script
3. Data file has no-two-lines which start with the same key word

   - if this constraint is broken, you will get all the matching lines
     when you look for the key.
   - that can be handled with a "`| tail -1`" to show just the first match (say)
4. You start saying `rtf` files but tag the question as `text`.
   If you have rich-text-format files, you should convert them to text files for this purpose.

here is a script for you,

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=","
#    -> to look for comma separated words in key.txt

for k in $(sed 's| ||' key.txt)
#          -----------> to make the search easier
do
  grep "^$k " data.txt
#       ----> look for key words matching at the start of each line
done
```

Here `key.txt` is your first file and `data.txt` is your second file.
The `for` loop sorts the output in the order of the keys.
The `sed` command removes any spaces you may have in the `key.txt` file to make searching easier.

**Update** on non-english characters (which is why it seems you say RTF file):
Look for `iconv` and get your RTF converted to UTF-8 -- I think `grep` can handle that.
If that is what you want to do your question should be rephrased as,

### "How to grep in rich-text-formatted files (on linux)?"

Answer (score 0):

Another option assuming your data file is 'data.txt':

```
for k in Apple Orange Banana Noodle Chip; do echo -n "$k, "; grep "^$k" data.txt; done
```

Comment: some question on txt, can the txt display some non-English char/word?

Answer (score 0):

This Perl script will do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $f1, '<', $ARGV[0]) || die "cannot open $ARGV[0] $!\n";
open (my $f2, '<', $ARGV[1]) || die "cannot open $ARGV[1] $!\n";

my $line=join('',<$f1>);
my @f2=<$f2>;

foreach my $e1 (sort split /, /,$line) {
    foreach my $e2 (@f2) {
        print "$e1, $e2" if ($e2=~/^$e1/);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't need the result sorted in the order of the keyfile:

```
sed 's/, /\n/g' keyfile.txt | grep -f - datafile.txt
```

In order to do the sorting, you could do something like this (in Bash):

```
sed 's/, /\n/g' keyfile.txt | grep -f - datafile.txt | sort | join -1 2 <(sed 's/, /\n/g' keyfile.txt | nl | sort -k2) - | sort -k2 | cut -d' ' -f1,3-
```